Need Help Modeling Chef’s Hat with Folds in Blender
I hope you’re all doing well. I’m currently working on a project where I need to model a chef’s hat with intricate folds, but I’m facing some challenges in figuring out the best approach. I have a reference image of the specific hat I want to model, but I’m struggling to translate it into a 3D model effectively.
Could anyone please guide me on the best techniques or workflows to achieve this? I’m particularly interested in how to create realistic folds and details while maintaining the overall shape of the hat. Any tips, tutorials, or step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!


Create a cylinder, subdivide it horizontally, assign it a vertex group at its top with the Gradient brush, create a ring object that you'll use to squeeze the hat, make sure that its face normals are facing inwards:

Give your cylinder a Cloth simulation, keep the default settings, except increase the Stiffness > Bending value up to 3 for example so that the folds are large enough, choose the vertex group as Pin Group, enable the Collisions > Self Collisions option:

Give Collision physics to the ring, animate it scaling down so that it squeezes the hat. When you're glad, apply the Cloth modifier:

